# Swift: El delegado en mi UISwitch no funciona

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo un TableView con un TableViewCell personalizado, dentro de este tengo un UISwitch entre otras cosas, lo que necesito es hacer que cuando se active/desactive este control se generen una serie de cambios en mi App, estoy intentando delegar de la clase que controla estos eventos (TableViewCell) a mi clase principal (ViewController) ya que requiero de ciertos datos de esta para poder controlar el total de cambios que necesito, lo que estoy intentado es lo siguiente:

Este es mi protocolo para esa delegacion:

```
protocol FinishChangeApplicationDelegate: class {
    func didFinishChangeApplication(value: Bool)
}
```

Este es mi TableViewCell:

```
class CategoryAppCellController: UITableViewCell{
    weak var delegate: FinishChangeApplicationDelegate?
    // otros controles
    @IBOutlet weak var swApplicable: UISwitch!
    
    @IBAction func changeApplicationValue(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        let isApplicable = sender.isOn
        delegate?.didFinishChangeApplication(value: isApplicable)
    }
}
```

Y esta es mi clase ViewController donde quiero recibir la delegacion y procesar las acciones:

```
class CategoriesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FinishChangeApplicationDelegate{
    // Otros metodos y propiedades

    // Metodo delegado
    func didFinishChangeApplication(value: Bool) {
        print(value)
        // Mis cambios y actualizar el TableView
        updateCategoriesTable()
    }
}
```

Pero el detalle que nunca llega el valor hasta aquí, el valor si cambia en el TableViewCell pero nunca se ejecuta mi método delegado, ¿que no estoy tomando en cuenta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar el delegado a la celda cuando las creas en esta función:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryAppCellController", for: indexPath) as? CategoryAppCellController

    //Aquí agregas el delegado
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell

}
```

Cuando cambias el valor te imprime el valor que es el código de la función `didFinishChangeApplication()`

Comment: Esa fue la solución, gracias, 4 horas investigando sin dar con ella. Aunque tengo otra pregunta, tengo otra vista con otra tabla similar pero en lugar de un UISwitch es un simple botón y con esa no tuve necesidad de agregar: `cell.delegate = self` funciono tal como el caso que exprese, ¿sería por el tipo de objeto? aun así gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @LuisFernando Hice una prueba con el botón sin delegate y no funciona. Debe estar en el código agregado para que funcione.